# Remove strings from a vector in R that match a rule

Tags: r

I have a vector of strings, for example a list of states:

```
USstates<-rownames(USArrests)
```

I would like to remove some States from the vector using a rule.
For instance, States that contains a double n in the name:
Pennsylvanya, Tennessee, Connecticut, Minnesota

How do I go about it?

Comment: `USstates[!grepl('nn', USstates)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
USstates_nn <- USstates[!grepl("nn", USstates)]
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `grep` with `invert` as `TRUE`

```
USstates_nn <- USstates[grep("nn", USstates, invert = TRUE)]
```

Comment: Even cooler: `grep("nn", USstates, invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)`